# Swipe functionality not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I followed a tutorial online that showed how to implement swiping in an Android application,but when I tested it on my device it doesn't swipe.Can anyone spot what wrong in this implementation?

My main class looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    EditText offsetLength,offsetDepth,ductDepth;
    Button calculate;
    //DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Intent intent1=new Intent(this,AboutActivity.class);
        final Intent intent2=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        offsetLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offLength);
        offsetDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offDepth);
        ductDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ductDepth);
        calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.a,null);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
            String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
            String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 

            double tri1,tri2;
            double marking1,marking2,marking3;

            double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
            double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);
            double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalcResult.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("number1", marking1);
            myIntent.putExtra("number2", marking2);
            myIntent.putExtra("number3", marking3);
            startActivity(myIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Calculating!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Must enter a numeric value!");


        }
//      
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the viewpageindicator so your app will be available for lower apis too and its much more easier here is the ofiical site:

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

and here is so nice tutorial:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2450910

or you can use OnSwipeTouchListener class witch is not recommended:

first create OnSwipeTouchListener class in your project and copy this code into that:

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();


      }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
```

}

and the usage is like this :

```
RelativeLayout n = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
        n.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
            }
            public void onSwipeTop() {
            }

            public void onSwipeBottom() {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Cool,Thanks,I'm gonna try out the `OnSwipeTouchListener` class you have shown.So I just create the listener class and set my main class to implement `OnSwipeTouchListener`? Then set the left,right.. gestures to the intent corresponding to the activity. Also are you sure this will work before I go hacking at the code.

Comment: @Brian J  yes! its tested!(no need to modify code) you don't need to implement OnSwipeTouchListener you have to just use setOnTouchListener and instead of new OnTouchListener you have to write new OnSwipeTouchListener()          :) finished :) and if my post helped dont forget to accept that!! :)